# Regex with negative lookahead and dot matches newline modifier (/s)

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

I have a PHP script and I need to match the last occurence of a specific string.

Let's say I have the following scenarios:

## 1

```
<p class="TPTexto" style="text-autospace: none; ">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FF0000">Este texto não substitui o publicado no DOU de  28.9.2006.</font>
</p>
```

## 2

```
Este texto abc def
<p class="TPTexto" style="text-autospace: none; ">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FF0000">Este texto não substitui o publicado no DOU de  28.9.2006.</font>
</p>
```

## 3

```
Este texto abc def
<p class="TPTexto" style="text-autospace: none; ">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FF0000">Este 
texto não substitui o publicado no DOU de  28.9.2006.</font>
</p>
```

## 4

```
Este texto abc def
<p class="TPTexto" style="text-autospace: none; ">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FF0000">Este <font></font>
texto não substitui o publicado no DOU de  28.9.2006.</font>
</p>
```

## 5

```
Este texto abc def
<p class="TPTexto" style="text-autospace: none; ">
<font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FF0000">Este            texto não substitui     o     publicado no DOU de  28.9.2006.</font>
</p>
```

I want to match `Este texto não substitui o publicado` in all cases, accepting some occasional garbage in between, like `Este <font></font>\ntexto não substitui o publicado`.

So I went with the following regex:
`/Este(?:.(?!Este))+?texto.+?n.+?o.+?substitui.+?o.+?publicado/uis`

The flags:
`u` to accept unicode characters
`i` to accept insensitive content
`s` to make dot (`.`) match newlines (so my negative lookahead works)

This way I **would** match the last `Este` and the following text, as I want, right? Nope! The `s` modifier kills it.
*(I'm using [this PHP tool](https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match-all) to test it btw)*

I don't know why the `s` modifier kills it in this case. Any help would be very appreciated.

---

I'm using PHP's `preg_match_all` on this project.

**Edit**:

Noticed it wasn't clear: I need the SECOND `Este texto...` not the first.

Comment: It looks to work on regex101 correctly, https://regex101.com/r/VHb2gm/1/. Generated PHP from there also seems to work, https://3v4l.org/ZR1fZ. Can you please clarify the issue, is it specific to *that tool*?

Comment: Why the downvote?
It is not working on regex101, on your example I'm not getting the LAST "Este texto", but the first "Este texto",

Comment: @user3783243 not sure why you downvoted and also voted to close. Not sure you read the question carefuly. Please remove the downvote and close vote.

Comment: Use `\A.*\KEste.+?texto.+?n.+?o.+?substitui.+?o.+?publicado`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/nsMRLj/1

Comment: @revo amazing! Seems to be working. I spent about 1h together with a colleague on this and we didn't make it work. Not sure what `\K` does though... Please add as an answer and clarify what it does and I will be glad to accept as the correct answer.

Comment: Please note that different input strings in your question shouldn't come all at once. In that case only the last occurrence is matched and returned.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. Thought it was clear on the question, but I was wrong, so I edited and clarified it.

Comment: I think this should have a duplicate but I couldn't find it so I'm going to post an answer. Someone may find a dupe and cast a close vote.

Comment: Tried finding a duplicate myself, before asking my own question. Hope someone did ask before me though, this way I can check the answers there also.

Comment: I remember answering the same question a few times before. So they exist, but unfortunately wasn't able to find them.

Comment: @dmmd Thanks for accusation, I hadn't done either. In my examples there were 5 matches and you have 5 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is OK. You could just prepend your regex with this:

```
\A.*\K
```

- `\A` asserts beginning of input string
- `.*` matches entire input string immediately and then tries to backtrack to match the next pattern which is `Este`
- `\K` resets output up to the point so that you'll see the desired string only

I removed the lookahead and made your regex a bit simpler. Putting it all together we have this:

```
\A.*\KEste.+?texto.+?n.+?o.+?substitui.+?o.+?publicado
```